# How would I style a string inside of textContent?

Tags: javascript, css

How would I change the style for the $ inside of the following:

```
var elSubTotal = document.getElementById('subTotal');
elSubTotal.textContent = '$' + subTotal;
```

So, I have 'subTotal' definded in my css as:

```
#subTotal {
color: red;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

The '$' ends up becoming red, and bold. I only want subTotal to be red and bold, not the string '$'. How would I style the strings inside of textContent when I am concatenating other selectors?

Comment: It needs to be a separate element inside.

Comment: Concatenating a string with a DOM element makes small sense. It will produce something like `"$[object HTMLDivElement]"`

Comment: What html are you starting with?

Answer (score 1):

As @JoshBeam pointed out, you need another tag. Use `innerHTML` and add a span tag around the subTotal:

```
var elSubTotal = document.getElementById('subTotal');
elSubTotal.innerHTML = '$<span>' + subTotal + '</span>;
```

Then change your CSS to target the span:

```
#subTotal span {
  color: red;
  font-style: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to had an other node (or a textnode) just before this one.

But, you can do it directly with some CSS:

```
#subTotal::before {
  content: "$";
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal
}
```

Hoped it helped.

Comment: I used this approach before just this weekend, but keep in mind that the "$" will not be selectable by users, which could be good or bad, depending on your situation. (In my case, that was part of the benefit.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to insert `$` before `#subTotal`. Do not mess with `textContent` or `innerHTML`, just prepend a text node:

```js
var elSubTotal = document.getElementById('subTotal'),
    node = document.createTextNode('$');
elSubTotal.parentNode.insertBefore(node, elSubTotal);
```

```css
#subTotal {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
Price: <span id="subTotal">100</span>
```

Comment: How would I style the '$' using this method?

Comment: @Dr.Doom2020 If you want to style it, you should prepend an element node instead of a text one.